# How fill dropdown menu

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine

I´m working with bootstrap and angularjs for the user interface and google appengine with java as a backend.
Just now I have a problem filling a dropdown menu, I see an empty list so I suspect that the problem is in the html code.

Front end:

```
<div class="dropdown" >
    <select id="mySelPartido" class="form-control">
        <option ng-repeat="partido in data.locations.partidos"
            ng-selected="partido.selected" ng-model="partido.partido">{{partido.partido}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

js in angular code (I debug this code and it works!):

```
$scope.status = 'loading...';
    $scope.partido = "Select partidos";
    $scope.data = {
        "locations": {}
    };

$http.get('https://myservice.appspot.com/_ah/api/partidoendpoint/v1/partido')
    .then(function (res) {
                        $scope.data.locations.partidos = res.data.items;
                        $scope.status = "loaded "
                                + $scope.data.locations.partidos.length
                                + " partidos.";
                    });
```

My service response from app engine backend:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "Partido",
    "appId": "s~myservice",
    "id": "5066549580791808",
    "parent": {
     "kind": "Provincia",
     "appId": "s~myservice",
     "id": "5086253011697664",
     "complete": true
    },
    "complete": true
   },
   "name": "Florencio Varela",
   "kind": "partidoendpoint#resourcesItem"
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "Partido",
    "appId": "s~myservice",
    "id": "5094432508477440",
    "parent": {
     "kind": "Provincia",
     "appId": "s~myservice",
     "id": "5086253011697664",
     "complete": true
    },
    "complete": true
   },
   "name": "La Matanza",
   "kind": "partidoendpoint#resourcesItem"
  }
 ],
 "kind": "partidoendpoint#resources",
 "etag": "\"PQS12KaO4-dKVfv_BcCoEkbIN9g/GvZKzZUnrHEP8TKWybTkd_fJbnc\""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the angular [documentation for select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Maybe try use the `ngOptions` directive in the `select` element. Example :

```js
function demo($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'foo' },
    { name: 'bar' },
    { name: 'baz' }
  ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="demo">
  
  <select ng-options="item.name for item in items"
          ng-model="selected">
  </select>
  
  <p>You have selected : {{ selected }}
  
</div>
```